# Cordova Plugin Expose JS Variable (Android) (CardFlight)

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Is there a way to set a Global JS Variable from inside a cordova plugin?

My situation is this; I have a library that is initiated from an Anonymous class. Once initiated it has a function that can be called via a pointer.

The function has no return; and merely sets a variable;

```
        reader = new Reader(getApplicationContext(), new CardFlightDeviceHandler() {

                ...
                /* Response */
                @Override
                public void readerCardResponse(Card card) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Device swipe completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                    mCard = card;

                    fillFieldsWithData(card);
                }
...

/* Call */
reader.beginSwipe();
```

(API Documentation)
https://getcardflight.com/docs/api/android#initialization

(Class Initiatlization)
https://github.com/CardFlight/android-demo/blob/master/android-demo/src/com/example/cardflight/MainActivity.java#L67

(Call)
https://github.com/CardFlight/android-demo/blob/master/android-demo/src/com/example/cardflight/MainActivity.java#L164

Comment: Are you trying to sett a variable from native side and make it accessible in js side? Why don't you add a getValue type of method to your plugin? I suppose I didn't understand the question...

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to set a JS Variable from the native side.

I suppose a getValue is doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You can store a value via `SharedPreferences` and access this value in JS.

You could use the `NativeStorage` plugin to retrieve a stored value.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159754/how-get-data-from-cordova-plugin-nativestorage-in-android-java), here a JS value is stored via NativeStorage and accessed in Android. Your application should be the other way around. Store a value with `SharedPreferences` with the correct `PREFS_NAME` (`"NativeStorage"`). And get the value via `NativeStorage`.

```
NativeStorage.getItem(<key>, function(value){}, function(error){});
```

NativeStorage on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage) or [Github](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage).