# How get data from cordova-plugin-nativestorage in android java

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-nativestorage

Good day,
I making native background mod for Cordova and I need get data from js to java.
I save data in js with plugin [cordova-plugin-nativestorage](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage), with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Save data</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        NativeStorage.setItem("somekey", "value", null, null);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

but my problem is: I don’t know how to get this data ("value") with java in background services without Cordova activity.

Backgroud services java:

```
package cz.oznameni;

public class Backgroundoznameni extends Service {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a change, so you should conveniently access the saved value.

Please, first reinstall the plugin:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-nativestorage
cordova plugin add https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage
```

This will install the dev version. This because this updated code isn't pushed to NPM (**UPDATE**: it is now not necessary to use the dev version, the version on NPM is just fine).

For retrieving the value with a key, I've written the following method:

```
String getValue(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return settings.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }
```

The `PREFS_NAME` should be declared as follows:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "NativeStorage";
```

The context should be `this` accessable within the `onCreate` method.

So overall it should look something like this:

```
    public class Backgroundoznameni extends Service {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "NativeStorage";
      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        String value = getValue(Backgroundoznameni.this, "somekey", null);
      }

      String getValue(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
            SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            return settings.getString(key, defaultValue);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: Code not tested!

EDIT: This is further documented in [this Github issue](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage/issues/53).